# how to remove spaces and new lines in a jquery script on the fly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a .js file that I want to remove the spaces and new lines, but on the fly or something that the source code show it without spaces/lines but I can in my FTP edit it normally.

I use PHP in my website. Any solutions on PHP or JS?

Comment: the search term you want is "JavaScript Minifier"

Comment: What will be the advantage of doing that?

Comment: Learn about [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), they are task runner for JavaScript with [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/), which will help you running tasks like minification, uglification  and etc for your HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript Minifier is nice, but I want, if exists, something that my .JS file stay with spaces in my server, so I can edit it later if I want, and in the browser version it shows without the spaces for quicker download times, reduced bandwidth consumption, obscuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something very simple you could perform a very simple string replace, along the lines of:

Remove whitespace characters:

```
input.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

More likely, you will want to use an existing minifier / uglifier such as [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) or the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?hl=en).

If you want the file on your server to remain the same, but the spaces to be removed when it is served to the client, you will need to pass it through some kind of proxy process.

This would involve something like the following:

- Client includes `<script src="files/script.js">`
- A route is registered on your server for `files/script.js`. When this route is hit, it requests the 'real' file contents from your server, removed the whitespace as explained above, and serves the result back to the client.

**However:** this sounds like a solution to the wrong problem.

As mentioned above, it is very common to pass javascript files through minifiers / compressors for production. This involves writing the files as you normally would (with all spaces) and when they are ready to be deployed, they are passed through the minifier which, among other things, removes whitespace. You original source file would still exist in source control (or FTP), but the version the client sees is passed through the minification first.

Comment: thank you! should I place this code in the top of my JS files?